# Reorder columns drag and drop with jquery and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using drag and drop of jquery dragtable.js. I am also using AngularJs to sort the table, but that doesn't work togther very good.

I want to be able to sort by a column by clicking on the th label, and be able to rearrange the columns. The problem now is that i only can move the columns but not sort them.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dragCustomers">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th ng-repeat="(key,label) in labels" ng-class="{ 'notdraggable' : key == 'fullname'}">
        <a href="" ng-click="reverseSortFunc(key,reverseSortArr[key])">
            {{ label }}
                <span ng-show="orderByField == key" class="sortIcon">
                    <span ng-show="reverseSortArr[key]">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span ng-show="!reverseSortArr[key]">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSortArr[orderByField]" class="name_table_dbl">
      <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.fullname }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.id_number }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.phone }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.email }}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my html code. And this is the sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/20554kxr/2/)

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are going to achieve and what the problem is?

Comment: I want to be able to sort the culumn by clicking on the th label, and be able to rearrange the columns. The problom now is that i only can move the columns and not sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i found my answare. I've added in the th tag this line:

```
<div class="dragHandle"></div>
```

And now it works great. Here is the updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/20554kxr/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, from a user experience point of view, it is confusing to let one action of mouse click have two effects: sorting and rearranging columns. Maybe you can add another element for sorting. Typically, it can be a triangle than can point upward or downward.

Secondly, in Angular, it is not suggested to manipulate HTML. If you need to manipulate HTML, create a directive to do it. [ng-table](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-table) is one plugin module you can use for table sorting, filtering and pagination.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reorder of the columns is not what i wanted. i want the option of drag & drop, and that was not what I saw in ng-table.

Comment: Sorry. A little confused. You said you "want to rearrange the columns" earlier, and now you said "reorder of columns is not what you want".

Comment: I meant that ng-table order column in different way not in drag and drop. And that is what I want.

Comment: You can use dragtable to rearrange columns and use ng-table to sort rows by value of clicked column. Am I correct in understanding your need in sorting?

Comment: Yes you are right @gm2008. But I can't combine both of them together to work as they needed